# how Angular EventListener on windows scroll is working?

Tags: angular, addeventlistener, nav, event-listener

I'm trying to figure out how i can track the position of the navbar bellow the landing page so that when the navbar reaches the top it will be sticky on top until you go back. I have tried many options here in the stackoverflow and other examples but with no luck.

Here is my code.

```
import {
 Component,
 OnInit,
 HostListener,
ElementRef,
ViewChild,
AfterViewInit
} from "@angular/core";
import { ScrollDispatcher } from "@angular/cdk/scrolling";

@Component({
selector: "app-nav",
templateUrl: "./nav.component.html",
styleUrls: ["./nav.component.css"]
})
export class NavComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
 @ViewChild("stickyMenu", { static: true }) menuElement: ElementRef;

 sticky: boolean = false;
 elementPosition: any;

   constructor(
  private el: ElementRef,
  private scrollDispatcher: ScrollDispatcher
) {}

 ngOnInit() {
  window.addEventListener("scroll", this.onWindowScroll, true);
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
this.scrollDispatcher
  .ancestorScrolled(this.el)
  .subscribe(event => this.onWindowScroll());
this.elementPosition = this.menuElement.nativeElement.offsetTop;
}

@HostListener("window:scroll", ['$event'])
onWindowScroll() {
const windowScroll = window.pageYOffset;
console.log("sss", windowScroll, this.elementPosition);
}
 }
```

And the html of the nav component

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark" cdkScrollable 
 [class.sticky] = "sticky" #stickyMenu>
<div class="container-fluid">
<a class="navbar-brand">Norbert</a>

<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
  <li class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="active">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="active">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#skills">Skills</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="active">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </li>
  <span class="et-hero-tab-slider"></span>
</ul>
</div>
</nav>

 <main class="et-main">
 <section class="et-slide" id="about">
<h1>ES6</h1>
<h3>something about es6</h3>
</section>
<section class="et-slide" id="skills">
<h1>Flexbox</h1>
<h3>something about flexbox</h3>
</section>
<section class="et-slide" id="contact">
<h1>React</h1>
<h3>something about react</h3>
</section>
```

Answer (score 3):

add something like this into your nav component controller:

```
@HostListener("window:scroll", [])
onWindowScroll() {
 // logic here to fix to top
}
```

or if you've got some kind of full height / width container that is actually what's scrolling (instead of the window):

```
<div class="scrolling-container" (scroll)="scrollHandler()"></div>
```

if this isn't easy to do, angular material has a helpful scroll module:

after installing angular material, import ScrollingModule into whatever module you need it:

```
import {ScrollingModule} from '@angular/cdk/scrolling';

imports: [... ScrollingModule ...]
```

then you attach a directive to the container:

```
<div class="scrolling-container" cdkScrollable></div>
```

and then in your nav component you just inject the dispatcher:

```
constructor(private el: ElementRef, private scrollDispatcher: ScrollDispatcher) {
  this.scrollDispatcher.ancestorScrolled(this.el).subscribe(event => this.scrollHandler())
}
```

docs: https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/api

Comment: I've tried this, and if i will put a console log it doesn't even trigger...I don't know what i`m doing wrong or not doing properly... I added exactly the same code underneath the ngOnInit

Comment: are you sure it's actually the window scrolling and not some full height / width container?

Comment: Hmmm - I'm not sure about this, I added it in the ts of nav component. The nav component has the nav and also the main sections where i want to scroll to go directly from the nav.

Comment: right click on your scroll bar and hit inspect, whatever tag is highlighted is what's scrolling. if it's not the body or html tag, you're not going to get a window scroll.

Comment: In this case it is the landing-page component... Another component, which represents the landing page only (Full-page)

Comment: then you need to attach your scroll listener to that element, or angular material has some scroll helper modules that you can look into

Comment: Oh - that's another challenge ... :D

Comment: chek out the scroll dispatcher module in angular material. you attach a directive from there to the scrolling container and then you can inject the scroll dispatcher service into whatever component to fire events on ancestor scroll

Comment: added a quick example of the material scroll module

Comment: Cool - i followed the updated version. I added the subscribe as you have it in the constructor but it says that 'Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type '(elementRef: ElementRef<any>, auditTimeInMs?: number) => Observable<void | CdkScrollable>'.'

Comment: my bad, updated it, you can also use `this.scrollDispatcher.scrolled()` to catch any scroll event

Comment: Okay so now, when you say scrollHandler you mean the onWindowScroll that Athnasios for instance wrote? I still get this error  Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined. I updated my code

Comment: make sure you're not accessing a viewchild till after the AfterViewInit hook, so do the subscription there

Comment: Bryan60 you are legend! Thanks for the help! sorted now !

Comment: Bryan60 you are legend! It is logging now when i call the handle function. However, when i create the viewchield..its throws that thing again...And i`ve put in the ngAfterViewInit the scrollDispacher

Comment: not sure what you mean by "create the view child", maybe throw some updated code in the question?

Comment: Okay - i already updated my code. Now in my console i get the sss and the windowScroll which is always 0 for some reason, also i get an undefined elementPosition. Does it make sense now?

Comment: window scroll y is 0 because as before, the window is not what's scrolling. the ancestor element is. the ancestorScrolled subscribe method will get the scrolled element which will have the required properties to determine scroll position (check the material docs at CdkScrollable for more)... as for the offsetTop, you're accessing it statically (single assignment), check it in the window scrollhandler

Answer (score 0):

[Check the mdn of getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/el/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)

[Check working example on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-so-scroll-count?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

In the html

```
<nav #navBar class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark">
```

And in ts.

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild('navBar') element: ElementRef;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
       window.addEventListener('scroll', this.onWindowScroll.bind(this), true);
    }

    onWindowScroll() {
      if (this.element) {
         const y = this.element.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().y;
         console.log('Y is:' + y);
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, and the console log doesn't trigger... :/

Comment: Added some more in ngOnInit for you to try.

Comment: Okay - Good, now i managed to trigger the scroll... However, now i have in the console some kind of error 'Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined'. I think it tries to get the  value from the html before is rendering? Shall i use something like ngAfterViewInit?

Comment: You need to get the element from the  viewchild. Change it to nav and let me know if it works. I did the change in the answer.

Comment: ViewChild isn't available till the AfterViewInit hook

Comment: Indeed. But why does this matter?

Comment: I did like you changed the code - but still the error is there :/

Comment: Figured it out while running it on stackblitz (see update). I needed to `bind(this)` for jsavascript as the prototype was getting out of scope and this was refering to the event listener callback scope.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Material CdkScrollable, which should be better for compatibility and performance reasons, you'll need to wrap window into an ElementRef and then manually create the CdkScrollable object, like that :

```
import {NgZone} from '@angular/core';
import {CdkScrollable, ScrollDispatcher} from "@angular/cdk/overlay";

constructor(
    private scrollDispatcher: ScrollDispatcher,
    private ngZone: NgZone
  ) {        
    const windowRef: ElementRef = new ElementRef<any>(window);
    this.scrollDispatcher.register(new CdkScrollable(windowRef, this.scrollDispatcher, this.ngZone));
    this.scrollDispatcher.scrolled().subscribe(x => console.log('I am scrolling'));
}
```